# Uploading files to a shared folder in a different machine than IIS hosted ASP.NET application gives error as Access to the path '...' is denied

Tags: .net, iis

I have an application in ASP.NET which is hosted on **IIS**. There is a code which has to save uploaded files to SharedFolder in a different machine than the application hosted in IIS. When I run the application in **IIS Express**, the application saves the uploaded files, but in the IIS hosted application gives exception as

> "Access to the path \AnotherMachine\Assets\test.pdf' is
>   denied."

I have already added **Everyone, IUSR and IIS_USRS** to the Shared Folder with Read/Write permissions but still no luck.

```
  protected void btnUploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "";
                string pathToSave = @"\\AnotherMachine\Assets\";

                if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
                {
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(pathToSave + FileUpload1.FileName);

                    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    lblMessage.Text = "The file is saved successfully.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Should I have to set any other permissions as well to make the application workable?

Comment: If your machines are in AD, run IIS application pool as a domain user and then on the file server grants permissions to that domain user.

Comment: @LexLi  In the application pool, I have clicked on Advanced Settings... and then in Identity, I have put the computer's (where the application is hosted in IIS) login username and password in Custom account. After that, the application is able to save the file in the shared folder. I don't if it is the right way of doing.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Why can it not be the right way? What concerns do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I made some test on my side. Fileupload should depend on application pool identity. 
If you monitor the operation with process monitor.
Then you should see this.

[image]
[image]

So next time if you don't know where should you grant permission. You could try process monitor.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon